# Slightly Curved Border In CSS

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to create a border in css so my image gets this curved side on the right.
[image: Sample image]
I tried just using `border-radius: 0 0 50% 0` but that didn't quite look like in the sample image.

Any ideas?

Comment: try third value in px, i.e border-radius: 0 0 30px 0;

Comment: Can you show in JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a solution called masking and clipping.
I will simply create an alpha mask for my curve and apply it on the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the value in px. And set the image as background-image of the div.

```css
#my{
  border:solid 2px red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:0 0 100px 0;
  background-image:url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be');
}
```

```html
<div id="my">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Thats more or less how it looks with my solution. The problem is that the curve is very monotone. The border in the sample image is stating at the top corner very slightly and gets much more curved at the bottom end

Comment: The border in the sample image is made with 2 vectors, maybe there is a way to use vectors also in css borders?

Comment: I can't see the image. The path is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

To get desired result you could use svg clipPath.
Example:

```html
<svg width="191" height="233" viewBox="0 0 426.2 515.9">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="path">
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M426.2,1c0,0-4.4,498.5-169.4,514.9H1V1H426.2z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image clip-path="url(#path)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/72/51/88/725188868ce404e3a9ade284a2187128--newport-jazz-festival-winter-beach.jpg" />
</svg>
```